# MySQL - Does a Table have a Specific Column Name

Tags: mysql

I can find numerous search results explaining how to search the database or information schema for a specific column name ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526688/get-table-column-names-in-mysql)).

Is there a query that will tell me whether a specific column name is in a table, where I already know the table I want to search?

The question is more specific than "Give me all column names of a table". It's more like, "Does this column exist in this table, yes or no?"

Ex: `IS COLUMN as_id IN TABLE assets`

Comment: If you know how to search `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns` to get all the column names, it should be obvious how to put that question into the `WHERE` clause of a query.

Comment: What stops you from adding one more `AND` into `WHERE` clause?

Comment: The second answer in the question you linked to even shows how to test the column name.

Comment: Ah, I see then, thank you. I thought there might be a more direct query, but I guess this one will do: `SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='my_database' AND `TABLE_NAME`='$table'`

Comment: `SELECT my_col_name FROM my_table LIMIT 1;` - if you don't get an error, then the column exists :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='{database name}'
AND table_name='{table name}' AND COLUMN_NAME='{column name}'
```

[How do I count columns of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492164/how-do-i-count-columns-of-a-table)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html